# Fixing a PathFinding code

Tags: java, libgdx, path-finding

I have this path finding code which does the first part of the finding by only going one square

```
public class PathFinding {

    static Vector2 start;

    static Vector2 end;

    static Cell[][] cells;

    static Node currentNode;

    static Arena arena;

    public static void calcPAth(Vector2 from, Vector2 to,
            Cell[][] mapCells, Arena a) {
        start = from;
        end = to;
        cells = mapCells;
        arena = a;

        List<Node> openList = new ArrayList<Node>();
        List<Node> closedList = new ArrayList<Node>();
        Gdx.app.log(PArena.LOG, "Lists Created");

        currentNode = new Node(null, start);
        openList.add(currentNode);
        Gdx.app.log(PArena.LOG, "Added start to openList");
        // check squares around this and add

        int startPX = (int) currentNode.parentV.x / 32;
        Gdx.app.log(PArena.LOG, "Start X" + startPX);
        int startPY = (int) currentNode.parentV.y / 32;
        Gdx.app.log(PArena.LOG, "Start Y" + startPY);

        Gdx.app.log("", "");
        //
        int MIN_X = startPX - 1;
        int MIN_Y = startPY - 1;
        int MAX_X = startPX + 1;
        int MAX_Y = startPY + 1;

        int startPosX = (startPX - 1 < MIN_X) ? startPX : startPX - 1;
        int startPosY = (startPY - 1 < MIN_Y) ? startPY : startPY - 1;
        int endPosX = (startPX + 1 > MAX_X) ? startPX : startPX + 1;
        int endPosY = (startPY + 1 > MAX_Y) ? startPY : startPY + 1;

        // Check boundaries on start cell
        for (int rowNum = startPosX; rowNum <= endPosX; rowNum++) {
            for (int colNum = startPosY; colNum <= endPosY; colNum++) {
                // All the neighbors will be grid[rowNum][colNum]

                if (!cells[rowNum][colNum].getTile().getProperties()
                        .containsKey("blocked")) {
                    Node node = new Node(currentNode, new Vector2(
                            rowNum, colNum));
                    if (rowNum != startPX && colNum != startPY) {
                        node.setMovementCost(14);
                    } else
                        node.setMovementCost(10);
                    openList.add(node);

                    System.out.print(node.getFValue() + "|");
                } else
                    System.out.print("B");

            }
            System.out.println("");

        }

        openList.remove(currentNode);
        closedList.add(currentNode);
        int n = openList.get(0).getFValue();
        int index = 0;
        for (Node temp : openList) {
            if (temp.getFValue() < n) {
                n = temp.getFValue();
                index = openList.lastIndexOf(temp);
                Gdx.app.log("n", "n = " + n);
            }
        }
        currentNode = openList.get(index);
        arena.colorSquare(currentNode.getVectorPos());

        // need to calc move cost;

        //

        Gdx.app.log("", "");
        openList.clear();
        closedList.clear();

    }
```

This is my Node class

```
public static class Node {

        int hVal;

        int gVal;

        int fVal;

        Node parentNode;

        Vector2 parentV;

        private Node(Node node, Vector2 p) {
            setParent(node);
            this.parentV = p;
            calcHValue();
        }

        public void setMovementCost(int c) {
            this.gVal = c;
            calcFVal();
        }

        private void calcFVal() {
            fVal = gVal + hVal;
            // Gdx.app.log("Node", "HVal = " + hVal);
            // Gdx.app.log("Node", "GVal = " + gVal);
            // Gdx.app.log("Node", "FVal = " + fVal);
        }

        private void calcHValue() {
            int x = (int) (parentV.x - end.x);
            if (x < 0)
                x *= -1;
            int y = (int) (parentV.y - end.y);
            if (y < 0)
                y *= -1;

            hVal = (int) (x + y) / 32;
            // Gdx.app.log(PArena.LOG, "Heuristic Value" + hVal);
        }

        private void setParent(Node node) {
            this.parentNode = node;
        }

        public int getFValue() {
            return fVal;
        }

        public Vector2 getVectorPos() {
            return parentV;
        }
    }
```

My problem is that my debugging outputs like this

```
15|11|15|
11|11|11|
15|11|15|
```

So basically it isnt actually calculating the total value. It is just adding the movement cost, not heuristic.

What is th problem? Am i missing a step?

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the Successor list i think. An A* does have a Successorlist and while the openlist isnt empty you do the following stuff:

```
while (openList.size() != 0) {
            successor.clear();
            q = openList.remove(); //first element of the prio queue
// generate your neighbornodes of q and add them to the successorlist
//after this you iterate over the successor and check if its your goalnode. 
//If so you do return it else you add it to the openlist. (still inside of the while!)
//Dont forget to check if the neighbor is inside of the close list! 
//if so you do not need to add it to the successorlist



//Here is how it does look at mine A*. It also contains a check if there is a betterone

// calc

    for (Node suc : successor) {
        if (suc.x == (int) this.screen.character.mapPos.x
                && suc.y == (int) this.screen.character.mapPos.y)
            return suc; //return the goalnode
        boolean add = true;
        if (betterIn(suc, openList))
            add = false;
        if (betterIn(suc, closeList))
            add = false;
        if (add)
            openList.add(suc);
    }
```

Last but not least you do delete the q note from the openlist and add it to the close ist.

```
            }
            closeList.add(q);
        }//end of while
```

Some more minor improvmements would be that you do add a compareable to the Node..

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Node o) {
    if ((this.g + this.h) < (o.g + o.h))
        return -1;
    else if ((this.g + this.h) >= (o.g + o.h))
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

also override the equals and the hashCode method for it for example like this:

```
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        // override for a different compare
        return ((Node) o).x == this.x && ((Node) o).y == this.y;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return x + y;
    }
```

After that your `openList` can be a `PriorityQueue<Node>` and the first object you are getting from the is always the one with the smallest h.

Dont forget to return our final Node to iterate over the getparent method to get the path.

---

```
private boolean betterIn(Node n, Collection<Node> l) {
    for (Node no : l) {
        if (no.x == n.x && no.y == n.y && (no.g + no.h) <= (n.g + n.h))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```